# How to slide a UIView right above a UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView that I want to slide from behind a UITabBar to be position right on top of it.

This doesn't work. My view does not appear.

```
- (void)showNotificationBar
{   
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 500, 320, 32);
    frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame) - frame.size.height;
    notificationBar.frame = frame;

    [self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.superview insertSubview:notificationBar 
                                                                  belowSubview:self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = notificationBar.frame;
        frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.parentViewController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame);
        notificationBar.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```

Comment: Do you want the notification bar to overlap the tab bar (occupy the same pixels on the screen), or to be north of the tab bar?

Comment: just north of the tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `frame.origin.y` like this:

```
frame.origin.y = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y;
```

In the animations block, set it like this:

```
frame.origin.y -= frame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to show in every view, you could do to things: either show it at the bottom of every view or show it in the application's window. I personally like this second approach better because it helps avoiding duplicate code:

```
CGFloat notificationBarHeight = 40.0f;
UIView *notificationBar = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y - notificationBarHeight, 320, notificationBarHeight)];
[self.window insertSubview:notificationBar atIndex:[[self.window subviews]count]];
```

Answer (score 0):

[self.view insertSubview:notificationView atIndex:1]; worked for me...